# How to fix an error with Vyper: invalid syntax (, line 168)

Tags: contract-development, sharding, vyper

I'm trying to figure out why the following line is giving the error at https://vyper.online/: `invalid syntax (, line 168)`.

Line 168 is `self.collator_pool.empty_slots_stack_top] = index)`.

```
@internal
def stack_push(index: int128):
    (self.collator_pool.empty_slots_stack[
        self.collator_pool.empty_slots_stack_top] = index)
    self.collator_pool.empty_slots_stack_top += 1
```

There's also this which is the other relevant part of the file:

```
collator_pool: public({
    # array of active collator addresses
    collator_pool_arr: address[int128],
    # size of the collator pool
    collator_pool_len: int128,
    # Stack of empty collator slot indices caused by the function
    # degister_collator().
    empty_slots_stack: int128[int128],
    # The top index of the stack in empty_slots_stack.
    empty_slots_stack_top: int128,
})
```

I don't think you'll need it but the whole file is available at https://github.com/Drops-of-Diamond/sharding/blob/develop/smc/sharding_manager_contract.v.py.

Comment: I think it might be due to the way you have broken up the statement in the parentheses. If Vyper is anything like Python that has caused me some issues every so often.

Comment: No, it's not that, I tried putting it all on one line, but I still got the same error. The use of parentheses allows line continuation.

`(self.collator_pool.empty_slots_stack[self.collator_pool.empty_slots_stack_top] = index)`

Comment: Ah okay. I haven't used Vyper so I'm just spit balling, but I took a look at some of your other internal function definitions, and noticed that they had a return statement at the end of them. Why not try having `stack_push` return an empty boolean and them compiling it again? See if that fixes the error.

Comment: I did think of that but I'm skeptical as it didn't mention this in http://vyper.readthedocs.io/en/latest, and in Python you don't need a return statement, if there isn't one the function will return `None`. The compiler is breaking at line 8, it hasn't got to `stack_push` yet. Nevertheless I did add `return None`, but it is still breaking the same way.

Comment: @hextet, FYI, adding `return None` caused an error: 

`line 170: Not expecting to return a value return None ----^`.

Comment: Yeah I think it must be the parentheses, I just added them again and I got an error at the same line, while previously I was fixing errors and got an error at line 198. This should be a problem with Vyper, parentheses should be supported in this way.

Comment: Interesting. Indeed does seem to be a problem with Vyper, i would think this syntax should most definitely be supported. Good work on the rust sharding implementation so far btw keep it up!

Answer (score 1):

The parentheses are causing the error. Putting the statement on one line without the parentheses causes it to compile. To still comply with PEP008, since implicit line continuation is not an option with Vyper here (although it should be, and I will report this issue to the Vyper team), explicit line continuation will still work, in this case:

```
@private
def stack_push(index: int128):
    self.collator_pool.empty_slots_stack[self.collator_pool \
        .empty_slots_stack_top] = index
```

I reported this at https://github.com/ethereum/vyper/issues/724.